# gspread lib fails email notification

Tags: gspread

I am using gspread lib and it doesn't send email notification for a shared spreadsheet, when I look at the sheet with sheet ID, I see I have access to it but I am not getting any emails.

I am using python 2.7.16,

any idea how to fix this?